# D3 force-directed layout and brush event

Tags: d3.js, brush, force-layout

I am new to the great world of D3.

I have a force-directed layout, I need to 'drag selecet' nodes(circles) in a force-directed layout.

I tried with this code:

```
    force = d3.layout.force()
      .size([bw,bh])
      .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
      .links(links)
      .linkDistance(60)
      .charge(-300)
      .on("tick", tick)
      .start();

    var svg = d3.select("#"+domID)
        .append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width",bw)
        .attr("height",bh)
        .attr("class", "d3_linkgraph")

    // Brush.
    var brush = d3.svg.brush()
        .on("brushstart", brushstart)
        .on("brush", brush)
        .on("brushend", brushend);

    function brushstart(p) {
        if (brush.data !== p) {
            cell.call(brush.clear());
            brush.x(x[p.x]).y(y[p.y]).data = p;
            }
        }

    // Highlight the selected circles.
    function brush(p) {
        //do something
    }
    // If the brush is empty, select all circles.
    function brushend() {

    }
```

but this doesn't work... please help.